# nginx URL rewriting regex when URL contains a specific word but not other

Tags: nginx, regex, url, pcre

Please consider the following URLs.

1. https://products.example.com/family/child
2. https://products.example.com/products/family/child
3. https://products.example.com/family/children
4. https://products.example.com/products/family/children

Among the four, I need to redirect one as follow: https://products.example.com/family/children

Which means that I want to redirect the URLs that do not contain the word `/products/` and `/children`. If the URL does not contain the word `/products/` but contain `/child` at the end, I need to replace the `/child` with `/children`.

UPDATE 1: I have 2 problems as below.

1. Identify the URL that are to be substituted.
2. Modify the identified URL as required.

I can identify the URL with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/54LotX/1) but not able to substitute.

[Update 2](https://regex101.com/r/54LotX/3): I think I found a way to identify:  `^(?!.*\/products(?:\/))(?:(.*)\/|$)?(?:child)$` and substitute: `$1/children`

Next problem is: the regex works with option `/m` only. Can this be modified to work without it as:

```
rewrite ^(?!.*\/products(?:\/))(?:(.*)\/|$)?(?:child)$ $1/children permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for what you've said above, however your question isn't as precise as it could be and this might not be exactly what you want.

The = means exact match. Remove it and I think you get a substring match. You'll can read the documentation for details.

```
location = /family/child {
  return 301 http://www.example.com/family/children;
}
```

Comment: Please check the update 2 from my question. I am able to identify and substitute the URL, however, it is working with /m (multiline) switch. Problem is, I do not have testing environment for troubleshooting so I need to make sure that the regex and rewrite will work on production. Could you please have a look?